# Displaying vector Maps in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, ipad

I am working in an App which displays the maps. I want to increase the zooming quality of the maps. For zoom to be clear, it should display the vector maps. I have vector maps in .svg format. After lots of searching I found that I can use **pdf** format or I can use the third party library like [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit). I am getting which approach I should follow.

Please suggest me the approach. Also, is it possible to draw the vector maps in the code itself?

Thanks & Regards,
Priya

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: @priya if some one comment or answer on your question you have to give them responce about

Comment: Please anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [Apple Image size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) iPad Pro size is 2732 x 2048 (landscape) mode so you don't need a image size for the **4096 × 3140** its really really big,

so make all images based on your need for the consider 2732 x 2048 and then use it.

You can compress image by using https://tinypng.com/ its really good and `50%` compress image size without loosing its quality.

Comment: Sorry for replying late Nitin. The 4096*3140 is the requirements of my project so the map will be very clear after zooming it to double size.

Comment: 2732 x 2048 is the @2x size max scale so i dont think there is need to image of  4096 × 3140 anyways you can use i suggest site to compress image size that does not lost image quality

Comment: No it didn't work for me. The image is losing the quality.

Comment: then there is no way to decrease its size you may load the image from web services API this is one of the great way else all things not possible that you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nitin. It is working. The reduced size is not making any difference in the UI. The site you have given didn't work for me as the mazimum size limit is 5MB. I did it with preview. Thanks a lot!!